# SQL Developer query: populating 1 column with 2 tables

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I have a table called Sales which have data since 1990, but on 2020,the data started coming from another table called SalesNew. So if i query first table i get nulls after 2020 and if i query second table i get null before 2020. Is there a ways to retrieve in one column from both tables so i dont get nulls? Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COALESCE function, which returns the first non-null value. E.g.:
SELECT COALESCE(sales.col1, salesnew.col1) from ...

Details: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-comparison-functions/oracle-coalesce/

Comment: For the lurkers: This is a valid answer in T-SQL as well

Answer (score 1):

You can use a view to combine the data in the two tables:

```
create view v_sales as (
    select . . . 
    from sales s
    union all
    selet . . .
    from salesnew sn;
```

Then when you query the view, you should see the data regardless of the time period.